# Wordpress Child Theme Called But Not Working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

As you can see here: http://www.mfdevco.com/solutions/
The child theme is being called in the head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" id="x-child-css" href="http://www.mfdevco.com/wp-content/themes/x-child/style.css?ver=4.0.7" type="text/css" media="all">`

But for some reason when I inspect element the changes aren't showing, this is all that's in my Child CSS file:

```
/*

Theme Name: X &ndash; Child Theme
Theme URI: http://theme.co/x/
Author: Themeco
Author URI: http://theme.co/
Description: Make all of your modifications to X in this child theme.
Version: 1.0.0
Template: x

*/

li.x-nav-tabs-item.active a {
    color: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: add main theme main style ex(@import style.css)

Comment: The styles are loading, but being superseded by the <style> block with the id "x-customizer-css-output", which comes after your linked stylesheet in the DOM

Comment: It's a theme so it's generated, not sure how I'd go about removing/editing?

Comment: Ok so the edits showed up an hour after I made the changes, which I deleted about an hour ago and they won't go now. Seems like a cacheing issue but from testing on mobile and other browsers the styles are still showing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there was a server side cache plugin which was screwing everything up.

All sorted now!